# How do I get Header in Php to work correctly?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am trying to fix why my Header command won't redirect back to my main page. It instead just stays on the Php display page.
Here is the php side after I submit my form.

[Php Script http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6602/a9j3.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6602/a9j3.png)

Here is the page that I get when my php is put into effect.

[Php display http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/6649/1qk3.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/6649/1qk3.png)

Here is my page it's suppose to redirect to...

[Html Main Page http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/8004/tulo.png](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/8004/tulo.png)

As you can see, I have no spacers in my header command for php. I've looked up multiple issues but never found anything that works.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post your actual code in future questions, not pictures of the code. :)

Comment: i wish i could down vote more, pictures- NO! you don't take a picture of your broken car to the garage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the line that says:

```
echo 'Full connection<br/>';
```

That line will ensure that no headers will be able to be sent after it. You can't output **anything** to the browser before a header call, including whitespace, HTML or this line.

I'm surprised you aren't getting an error when this happens, it's probably because your [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) levels are turned down. It's often a good idea to have error reporting turned up high on your local machine when testing so you'll see errors like this and can fix them straight away:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: So should I add the error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of the php or...?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the echo early on is causing the problem. Outputting any content renders further header calls redundant.

Try commenting out that line and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. When using header-Location for redirection, be sure you don't let anything echo-ing. the **HTML content needs to be empty**
2. URL in `header("Location:http://...URL...");` should be full absolute path (best practices)